# How to append a line of text to a existing file in ionic 2?

Tags: file, ionic2

I thought it was a silly question, but...

I'd tried try `writeExistingFile(path, fileName, text)` but it replace the file.

I'd tried `writeFile(path, fileName, text, true)`, the same

I'd tried `writeFile(path, fileName, text, false)` and I got PATH_EXIST_ERROR

I can read the file, append the newline, write the file... but it seems a little crazy! 
Someone help?

P.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:
`writeFile(path, fileName, text, {append: true, replace: false})`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris! I did't suspect that options was a object. My shame!

Comment: You're very welcome! Please don't forget to mark as answered :-) and/or upvote thus answer.

Comment: Where can I find a description of Options parameter?

Comment: Good question, this is omitted from the docs and I got the answer by looking at the sources (check ng-cordova.js). IMHO this is a glaring omission, which may be corrected by now but I answered you based on personal experience

Comment: I got it from cordova docs. A few lines, and since the documentation is named, it should also be into the ionic document ...
`options WriteOptions 
replace file if set to true. See WriteOptions for more information.` 
at [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)